# Swift: Custom Setter For CoreData NSManagedObject

Tags: ios, core-data, swift, setter

How to implement custom setter for `NSManagedObject` in Swift. I need to do task before setting the `NSMangedObject` Property.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

My recommendation would be to use KVC. Maybe not the most elegant solution, but conceptionally a logical application of KVC.

Observe a change of the attribute. Register for the change in `init(entity:insertIntoManagedObjectContext:)` or maybe better in `awakeFromFetch` and `awakeFromInsert`, and remove the observer in `willTurnIntoFault`.

```
init(entity: NSEntityDescription!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext context: NSManagedObjectContext!) {
    super.init(entity: entity, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: context)
    addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "attribute", options: NSKeyValueObservingOptions.New | NSKeyValueObservingOptions.Old, context: nil)
}


override func observeValueForKeyPath(keyPath: String!, ofObject object: AnyObject!, change: NSDictionary!, context: CMutableVoidPointer) {
    if (keyPath == "attribute") {
           // do what you need to do
    }

}
```

Updated for Swift 3:

```
init(entity: NSEntityDescription!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext context: NSManagedObjectContext!) {
    super.init(entity: entity, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: context)
    addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "attribute", options: [.old, .new], context: nil)
}

override func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?, of object: Any?, change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey : Any]?, context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {
    if keyPath == "attribute" {
           // do what you need to do
    }
}
```

Comment: Specifically this solved my problem `options: NSKeyValueObservingOptions.New | NSKeyValueObservingOptions.Old`. Thanks.

Comment: I think KVO approach will fall apart if NSManagedObject turns into fault.

Answer (score 7):

There is even a simpler way how to do it without managing KVO subscription. It can be done simply by overriding `didChangeValueForKey:` like this:

```
 override func didChangeValueForKey(key: String) {
    super.didChangeValueForKey(key)

    if key == "propertyName" {
        // do something now when propertyName changed
    }
}
```

Comment: I used this as well, unfortunately when you look at the documentation you'll notice a `You must not override this method.` warning. So I guess this could probably have some unexpected effects.

Comment: @erikAigner that is true. I am using this approach for quite some time and I believe that the warning in documentation is mostly for performance concerns, since whole KVO/KVC is relaying on this method (together with `willChangeValueForKey:`). The accepted answer suggesting KVO has the same performance characteristics as this one. So far I havent find a single unexpected side effects of using this approach.

Answer (score 0):

## TL;DR

I would recommend overriding `awakeFromInsert` instead of the `init` because it doesn't require KVO and the object properties can be accessed safely. Overriding any of the `init` methods is risky and unnecessary since the object + its properties may not be ready to be accessed (faults).

## Explanation

Overriding any of the `init` methods is risky and unnecessary since the object + its properties may not be ready to be accessed (faults). However, it’s very useful to be able to prepare an `NSManagedObject` before it starts accepting data. Perhaps we want to set up some logical defaults or assign some relationships before handing the object to the user. In these situations, we use `awakeFromInsert`. As the name implies, this method is called right after the `NSManagedObject` is created from an insert call.

This method is called before any values are set and is a perfect opportunity to set default values, initialize transient properties, and perform other tasks that we would normally handle in the `init` method. This method is called exactly once in the entire lifetime of an object. It won’t be called on the next execution of the application, and it won’t be called when an object is read in from the persistent store. Therefore, we don’t need to worry about overriding values that have been set previously. When we override this method, we should be sure to call `super.awakeFromInsert()` at the very beginning of our implementation to allow the `NSManagedObject` to finish anything it needs to before we begin our code.

## Handy ObjC Shortcut in Xcode Snippets (Xcode 12)

[image: Xcode Snippet for awakeFromInsert1]

**NOTE:** It's very easy to add your own Swift snippet for this manually. You can also try some GH repo. e.g  for [Swift 4 snippets](https://github.com/burczyk/XcodeSwiftSnippets).